# XGBoost hyperparameters depend on number of samples, how can I avoid constantly retraining as I collect more samples?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I'm currently using this:

```
XGBRegressor(
    learning_rate=0.2, n_estimators=100, max_depth=6, min_split_loss=0.1, min_child_weight=1,
    reg_alpha=2, reg_lambda=2, scale_pos_weight=1, nthread=3, subsample=0.5, colsample_bytree=0.5
)
```

With `n` samples, this works well. With `2n` samples, it overfits. With `n/2` samples, it underfits. I have to change the `learning_rate` and `reg_alpha` whenever I change the number of samples. Is there a systematic way to make the hyperparameters independent of the number of input samples?

I could just make the hyperparameters variables dependent on the number of samples, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do so.